# checking to see if the image is the same

Tags: java

So i have a lot of questions to this but first here is my assignment.

> Write a method public Picture authenticate(Picture p) which checks to
>   see if ”this” picture and the picture p are identical. It returns a
>   new picture that it the same size as ”this” picture. For each pixel
>   position in the original picture ”this”, compare the color of that
>   pixel with the color of the pixel in the same position from second
>   picture. If the two pixels have the same color (i.e. the original is
>   not modified in the copy), set the color of this position in the
>   resulting picture to white. If the two pixels do not have the same
>   color, set the color of this position in the resulting picture to the
>   color of the pixel from the original picture. Return the resulting
>   picture. If the two pictures are not the same size, the resulting
>   picture should contain all black pixels

This is my code as of right now

```
public Picture Authenticate(Picture p)
{

  Pixel sourcePixel = null;

  Pixel targetPixel = null; 

  Picture result = new Picture(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

  for(int sourceX = 0, targetX= getWidth()-1; sourceX < getWidth(); sourceX++,targetX++)
  {
    for(int sourceY = 0, targetY= getHeight(); sourceY< getHeight(); sourceY++,targetY++)
    {
      sourcePixel = this.getPixel(sourceX,sourceY);
      targetPixel = result.getPixel(targetX, targetY);
    }
    if (sourcePixel.getColor() == targetPixel.getColor())
      targetPixel.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    else
       targetPixel.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  }
  return result;
}
```

**Here are my questions:**

1. How do i make p in the authenticate parameter fit into this?
2. Am i going about this the right way within the loop?
3. With my if and else statement, i feel as if that is not even close
   to changing the pixel i need tooa

Comment: Come on downvoters, give the new guy a break. In contrast to most of the lazy, totally unresearched questions, this poster has actually made a serious effort to solve the problem.  OK, so he asked more than one question but they're all related.  Don't be so ready to knee-jerk downvote without actually reading and understanding the question completely.

Comment: thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How do i make p in the authenticate parameter fit into this?

`this` is your source image; `p` is the target image;  `result` is where you place the output pixels resulting from comparing the source and target.

> 2. Am i going about this the right way within the loop?

Yes, but the if/else statement belongs inside the inner loop

> 3. With my if and else statement, i feel as if that is not even close to  changing the pixel i need to

You are close. Keep working on it and step through the code in your debugger to see what is actually happening.

Don't get discouraged, this is closer than you think.